# how to make a copy to clipboard button with js

Tags: javascript, html, copy

so i was trying to make a button that when clicked it copy a value from a variable

like

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard()">COPY</button>
```

and then on that function it takes the element to copy from a variable like

```
var copyids = {
"ids": [
{
"name": "id1",
"id": 192389021
},
{
"name": "id2",
"id": 123879032
},
{
"name": "id3",
"id": 149018292
},
]
};
```

so like `copyids.ids[0].id` and it copy that value

i hope its understandable

Comment: In your button html is no id,class or name attribute specified. You need to add something. Otherwise you click it and there is no connection to the array of objects.

Comment: @BernhardBeatus when its clicked it calls a function and that function has to copy and id value from the variable i wrote, i dont need any id on class name on the button

Comment: Yes, but how will you specify that for example copyids.ids[0].id so the first element will be copied or do you like the whole array of objects schould be copied? Please explain me what you link to do exactly.

Comment: @BernhardBeatus it doesnt matter i just need the code then the element i want to copy i can change that, make like that button copy ```copyids.ids[0].id``` and its ok

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
function copyToClipboard() {
    let temp = document.createElement('textarea');
    temp.value = copyids.ids[0].id;
    document.body.appendChild(temp);
    temp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(temp);
}
```

Comment: [execCommand is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Answer (score 0):

To copy, you will need to select before what you want to copy. Maybe you should put the data of the variable somewhere and copy it.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Answer (score 0):

I made you a solution with the ability to select the desired data cell from the array. I've added a `select` tag for you, listing the **name** of each cell.

And at the choice of a specific `option` with you copy **id** in accordance with the specified **name**.

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
    var copyids = {
        ids: [
            {
                name: "id1",
                id: 192389021,
            },
            {
                name: "id2",
                id: 123879032,
            },
            {
                name: "id3",
                id: 149018292,
            },
        ],
    };

    let selectIndex = document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex;
    let storage = document.createElement("input");
    storage.value = copyids.ids[selectIndex].id;
    console.log(storage.value);
    document.body.appendChild(storage);
    storage.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(storage);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyToClipboard()">COPY</button>
<select>
    <option value="id1">id1</option>
    <option value="id2">id2</option>
    <option value="id3">id3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `execCommand` method has been deprecated, and it might not be supported by newer releases.

However, there is a [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) that you can use in it's place.

To let the user select what to copy from your list:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard()">COPY</button>
<select>
    <option value="id1">id1</option>
    <option value="id2">id2</option>
    <option value="id3">id3</option>
</select>
```

Then your function can work like this:

```
function copyToClipboard() {
var copyids = {
    ids: [
        {
            name: "id1",
            id: 192389021,
        },
        {
            name: "id2",
            id: 123879032,
        },
        {
            name: "id3",
            id: 149018292,
        },
    ],
};

let selectedIndex = document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex;

navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyids[selectedIndex].name);
```